# Paypal checkout with django rest frame work

Tags: javascript, django-rest-framework, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Ok so at present, when a user enters checkout page their cart contents are transferred  into a pending order object on my back end.

Once shipping form is submitted a shipping address is added to this order and the make payment button is revealed.

Now here is the problem I am having, I am stuck on what to pass through my script for paypals check out as my orders are already created prior to making payment.

Would it be simply easier to add my Order Creation scripts to the make payment button rather than order creation on page load? The only issue I saw with this method was the shipping address been added, as the form is filled and submitted prior to payment button

Here is my current script, some help on the creatOrder section would be helpful:

```
<script>
        paypal.Buttons({
            style: {
                color:  'blue',
                shape:  'rect',
            },
            // Return the order ID of the previously created order
            createOrder() {
                return fetch(`/api/orders/`, {
                  method: "POST",
                  headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
                  },
                  // use the "body" param to optionally pass additional order information
                  // like product skus and quantities
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                    cart: [
                      {
                        sku: "YOUR_PRODUCT_STOCK_KEEPING_UNIT",
                        quantity: "YOUR_PRODUCT_QUANTITY",
                      },
                    ],
                  }),
                })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((order) => order.id);
              },
            // Finalize the transaction on the server after payer approval
            onApprove(data) {
                const orderId = data.orderID;
                const endpoint = `/api/orders/${orderId}/`;
                return fetch(endpoint, {
                  method: "PATCH",
                  headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                    order_status: "C",
                  }),
                })
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((orderData) => {
                // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                const transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                alert(`Transaction ${transaction.status}: ${transaction.id}\n\nSee console for all available details`);
                // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
                // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                // Or go to another URL:  window.location.href = 'thank_you.html';
              });
            }
          }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
```

Comment: you say you already have the order, wouldn't it be better to connect to PayPal from your backend directly? using a such script, is meant more for those that can't change their backend... in case you go ahead with this script, you are missing after you send what PayPal requires for creating the order, at the end you can notify your backend that the order was created and pass the `order.id` or the whole `order` object, so you have a log... same `onApprove` at the end send to your backend that the order is processed...

Comment: Yes in my head it was: 1) create cart 2) checkout page > create pending order 3) creating shipping address for that order 4) process payment with orderid.    The other way around it in my head was 1) create cart 2) checkout page > create shipping address, *In this method I cannot link the address to an order because it is not yet created* 3) process payment and create order on my back end simultaneously.

Comment: "I cannot link the address to an order because it is not yet created" - no, not yet, but I'm sure you have already an internal ID to the cart, a sessionId for example, you can create orders in your backend without the need or an `orderId` from Paypal, you can have your own and use it while you don't have PayPal's, right? or am I not understanding the question correctly? 

Comment: I have currently got to the stage where. The order is now not created until payment button is clicked. Then order and address are successfully added to my back end(ill add order id to the address but order set to complete) but paypal keeps throwing me an error, Expected an order id to be passed.

Comment: sorry, I'm failing to understand the issue  I'll come later, maybe we can [chat instead](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253285/question-76078844) to exchange some ideas around...

Comment: That would be brilliant I'd really appreciate the help